# How to create a dictionary from a couple of tuples of the same size?

Tags: python, dictionary, constructor

Consider I have the two following tuples:

```
keys=("second", "minute", "hour", "day")
values=(1, 60, 60, 24)
```

I would like to create a dictionary that has the `keys` tuple as keys and the `values` tuple as values. Here's my naive way of doing it:

```
d={}
for i in xrange(len(keys)):
    d[keys[i]] = values[i]
```

Is there an easier more elegant way of doing this?

I work primarily with Python2.7, so I would prefer the answers to privilege this version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `zip` function turns a pair of iterables into a list of pairs.  The `dict` constructor accepts a number of forms of arguments, one of which is a sequence of (key, value) pairs.  Put the two together, and you get just what you want:

```
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> keys=("second", "minute", "hour", "day")
>>> values=(1, 60, 60, 24)
>>> dict(zip(keys,values))
{'second': 1, 'hour': 60, 'minute': 60, 'day': 24}
```